# Show a specific row and columns in Bootstrap json table

Tags: html, json, filter

I'm using this json data in a Bootstrap table. http://codepen.io/nty_/pen/gLZwQV

```
{
        "dex": "#004",
        "name": "Litten",
        "abilities": "Blaze <br> Intimidate",
        "type": "FIRE",
        "hp": "45",
        "att": "65",
        "def": "40",
        "satt": "60",
        "sdef": "40",
        "speed": "70"
},
    {
        "dex": "#024",
        "name": "Pichu",
        "abilities": "Static <br> Lightningrod",
        "type": "ELECTRIC",
        "hp": "20",
        "att": "40",
        "def": "15",
        "satt": "35",
        "sdef": "35",
        "speed": "60"
},
    {
        "dex": "#045",
        "name": "Meowth",
        "abilities": "Pickup <br> Technician <br>Rattled",
        "type": "DARK",
        "hp": "40",
        "att": "35",
        "def": "35",
        "satt": "50",
        "sdef": "40",
        "speed": "90"
}

<thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="dex" rowspan="2">#Number</th>
                <th data-field="name" rowspan="2">Name</th>
                <th data-field="abilities" rowspan="2">Abilities</th>
                <th data-field="type" rowspan="2">Type</th>
                <th rowspan="1" colspan="6">Base Stats</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="hp">HP</th>
                    <th data-field="att">Att</th>
                    <th data-field="def">Def</th>
                    <th data-field="satt">S.Att</th>
                    <th data-field="sdef">S.Def</th>
                    <th data-field="speed">Speed</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
```

I would now like to have a second table, filtered to specific columns from only one entry. e.g. - 
Only the base stats (hp, att, def, satt, sdef, speed) like so: http://codepen.io/nty_/pen/MbZjxo without having to remove any data from the json. 
Would I be able to filter that out with a script? And how would I go about doing it?

Comment: If you need a different table, haven't you already done it in the second example (http://codepen.io/nty_/pen/MbZjxo)?
If you need to show only specific rows in the same table you can use the `filterBy` method as described here: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/ ...(combined with `hideColumn` and `showColumn`)

Comment: @Giovazz89 That's exactly what I'd like to do, but I'm not sure how to make it work with `filterBy` as i'm not so good with scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

When your event gets triggered (e.g. `$(document).on('click', 'yourSelector (e.g. tr)', function(){ ... }`) or whenever you like you have to call something like:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {'dex': 'the dex number (e.g. #004)'});
```

in case of clicking on a row, for example, you should do

```
$(document).on('click', '#table tr', function(){
   // get the current table and filter by dex number (first <td>)
   var currentTable = $(this).closest('table');
   currentTable.bootstrapTable(
      'filterBy',
      { 'dex': $(this).find('td').first().text() }
   );
   // hide columns
   currentTable.bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'dex');
   currentTable.bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'name');
   currentTable.bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'abilities');
   currentTable.bootstrapTable('hideColumn', 'type');
});
```

when you want to return the table to it's original state you just `.('filterBy', {})` and instead of `hideColumn` use four `showColumn` and you are done!